# php implode huge array

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have a huge PHP array of the form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
    [1] => ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L')
    [2] => ('M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R')
    ....
    [30000] => ('S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X')
)
```

As you can see, my array contains 30,000 entries. I'm trying to use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to convert my array to a string of the form:

```
$values = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'), ('M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'), ('S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X')
```

To be able to do a MySQL INSERT query. So in order words, I'm trying to insert 30,000 entries into a database table in one shot (without doing it in a loop or something) like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES $values;
```

The problem I'm having is that the implode function doesn't seem to implode my gigantic array. When I try to debug the string to see if my array has been imploded, I get empty string or something.

Does anybody know how I can fix this or if there is a better way to do this? Again, I don't want to query my database 30,000 times, I just want to do the insert at once.

Thank you

Comment: I think `implode` is for joining strings..

Comment: Is `('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')` stored in your array as a string or as an array?

Comment: Have you tried to use the same code but with a more managable-sized array?

Comment: It would be helpfull to see your "implode" code

Comment: ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F') is stored as string

Comment: with **=> ('A','B'...)** you tell the array that comes a string A and a string B that means not, it comes as a whole string like => " ('A','B', ...) " .  And don't forget all " ' " are gone. f.e. $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated; // == "lastname,email,phone" all ' are gone.

Answer (score 3):

`implode` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays. The values at each of your indices should be enclosed in double-quotes, so that they're interpreted as strings:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')"
    [1] => "('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L')"
    [2] => "('M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R')"
    ....
    [30000] => "('S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X')"
)
```

Once you're dealing with a one-dimensional array, `implode()` will work.

Comment: When I call gettype on ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), it says <string>. Therefore ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F') is strored as a string, not an array

Comment: Hmm...how are you using `implode()`?

Comment: Actually the code works, I just found out that was a Google Chrome problem, for some reason Chrome did not show me any output, but when I switched to Firefox, I got my output

Answer (score 3):

To do it with PHP, this will handle the multidimensional array you have given:

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    $values[] = "('".implode("','", $arr)."')";
}

$values = implode(",", $values);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES $values;
```

I would suggest you use `transactions`. Read up here for [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a transaction (assuming you are using MySQL)?  That way you can build up your query then submit it in one go?

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: OP clearly stated that `implode` is not functioning the way he thinks it does. The issue has nothing to do with the large insert.

Comment: @Matt OP also asked if there was a better way of doing this, and that he didn't want to query the DB 30k times.  Only offering an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

You're not joining strings, you're imploding arrays. If your data structure was proper strings, it'd dump more like

```
[0] => "(a,b,c)",
       ^-------^---
[1] => "(d,e,f)", 
       ^-------^--0
etc...
```

Note the quotes I've highlighted within. You'd first have to implode each of those sub-arrays individually, then implode the parent array,e .g.

```
foreach ($yourarr as $key => $subarr) {
    $yourarr[$key] = "('" . implode("','", $subarr) . "')";
}
$bigstring = implode($yourarr);
```

Plus, this also depends on the individual values in your child arrays not containing SQL metacharcters, like `'`. Be very very careful doing this sort of thing, because you can inject yourself and kill the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
$rows = array();

foreach($originalArray as $row){

   $rows[] = '(' . implode(',' $row) . ')';

}

$finalString = implode(',', $rows);
```

Though I would split the query in chunks of let's say 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Implode isn't the job for this, you want to look at using a prepared SQL statement, then iterate through the array, executing the statement for each array.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
foreach($your_array as $entry) {
    // execute the prepared sql statement here

}
```

Comment: It's a mistake to loop through queries. You should just use one query to do it all. Think about server performance to execute 30000 queries